# Removing php extension with .htaccess does not work

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I use the following code on my site elixnews.com to remove php extension from:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

To remove www and php extension from my links, but it doesn't work: http://elixnews.com/todays_news - What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Will do the work.

Comment: It doesn't work :/